# Facebook Like align with Safari on iPad

Tags: css, alignment, facebook-like

I'm having trouble with the Facebook like button alignment but only in Safari on the iPad. Works fine with Safari on OSX. Here's an [example](http://goo.gl/WrmVvB)

What CSS is missing for it to be left aligned in one row for the iPad?

Comment: how come every time I submit a question during the weekend does it never get answered?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when it's being sized down the buttons are getting cramped in the left column. I noticed once it sizes lower than an ipad resolution it changes to the mobile layout. For the ipad size you should use a percentage for the primary column:

```
#primary {
padding: 0;
width: 60%;
}
```

The images still break into two row however, maybe hide one image/social share for ipad (display:none) so they all fit or find a smaller image for the reddit share, it's quite large.